# how to get return value of a non-blocking function with an await on it

Tags: javascript, callback

Lets say i have the following function:

```
async function commentMediaId(ig, media_id, commentContent, commentIfAlreadyCommented = false, extraInfo = new Object(), callback) {

    try {
        let alreadyExists = ig.db.get('comments').find({media_id: media_id}).value();
        alreadyExists == undefined ? false : true;
        if(alreadyExists && !commentIfAlreadyCommented) {
            console.log('Already commented'.yellow);
            return "already_commented";
        }

        if(commentIfAlreadyCommented || !alreadyExists){
            await ig.media.comment({
                module_name: 'profile',
                mediaId: media_id,
                text: commentContent,
            });


            return callback('success');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return callback('not success');
    }

}
```

then I am calling the following function (i do not want to use await here because it will block):

```
commentMediaId(object, 'someid', 'some string');
```

how can i seet a callback on commentMediaId such that when it returns i get the value of success or not success ?

I basically wanted to do as follows

```
commentMediaId(object, 'someid', 'some string', function(result) {
   if (result == 'success')



});
```

but I am getting a bunch of syntax error.. any ideas on how to implement it ?

Comment: `callback()` is a syntax error

Comment: @dandavis I have edited a couple of those typos out of the question.

Comment: If you're using promises and `async`/`await`, you should not pass a callback.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an `async` function, you are working with the `Promise` interface, which exposes a `.then()` method. You can pass a callback into this method, and the callback will automatically be invoked for you when a value is returned from the `commentMediaId` function:

```
commentMediaId(object, 'someid', 'some string') 
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
;
```

Finally, you need not take in a `callback` parameter in the `commentMediaId` function. You can omit the `callback` and simply return the values directly. That is the whole idea of the async/await "syntactic sugar", it makes it feel more like a regular function without the need for callbacks.

E.g. the following:

```
return callback('success');
```

...should be changed to the following:

```
return 'success';
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have some typos - `asyn` should be `async` and you also have an extra parenthesis in the last argument to the function `commentMediaId(...otherArgs, callback(){}` instead of `commentMediaId(...otherArgs, callback){}`

Comment: I think these are just typos in the question. I have edited the OP's question to fix them. The problem itself is a different issue.